# Is the current form of Gita is authentic as what Krishna actually said or interpolated?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhagavad-gita, arjuna

Only Arjuna and Sanjaya could hear the Gita messages, that were said by Krishna in Kurukshetra. After that, Arjuna was involved in the war of Mahabharata. Anywhere I have never heard that Arjuna writing or dictating Bhagawad Gita after the war was over.

Is the current Gita we read/hear today, exactly same as it was uttered by Krishna?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question a little more. I am not sure what your question is...

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, done. Probably the way of expressing in English was not right. Seeing this for the first time. It was actually a question which I wanted to ask as well. Sometimes, some of the verses, I too feel interpolated in Gita. But that can be kept for another day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maha Acharya Veda Vyasa was also witness to the Bhagavad Gita through telekinesis. His work called the Jaya an 18 chapter sacred hindu text constitutes the Bhagavad Gita.

Vyasa through his divine sight describes the universe, planets and stars in vivid detail. He also talks of several tribes, clans and cultures across the world. The Jaya deals with these diverse subjects of geography, history, warfare, religion and morality. In it is mentioned the Mahabaratha and the gita.

Hope this answered your question.

Comment: You should cite sources.